# Path name that will work on all OSs

Tags: operating-system, pathname

I have created a program to download a file and put it in a specific location but I cant get it to work on all systems. What could i change this to to make it work on all operating systems. 
/Users/anthonybuttillo/Library/Application Support/minecraft/mods/Enderized.zip

Comment: What do you mean by *ALL OSs*? There's quite a few out there... Simply put, you can't.

Comment: Do you mean this "specific location" for each OS?

Comment: @m0skit0 I'd like it to work on windows and mac.

Comment: Windows and Mac is not "all OSes". That's _two_ OSes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in **this** specific case (a Minecraft mod) is relatively simple because the place where a Minecraft installation resides is standardized.  As can be read [here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/124583-guide-how-to-install-mods-for-minecraft/) the Minecraft installation folder is

- Windows Vista/7: C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft
- Windows XP: C:\Documents and Settings\YourUserName\Application Data\.minecraft  (note - both Windows variations can be found through the `APPDATA` environment variable)
- Linux: /home/Your User Name/.minecraft
- Mac OS/X: ~/Library/Application Support/minecraft

So, just detect the OS and starting from the user's home directory ( `String s1 = System.getProperty("user.home", ".");` in Java ) you can build the required path.